# Hiding items on my sidebar that are not shown entirely

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar on my page for showing several items (one below the other). My sidebar is fixed on the right side of my page so when the user scrolls the page, the sidebar doesn't move. Some items on my sidebar may be partially shown and that depends on the height of the page.

**My question: is it possible to completely hide the items that are cut off?**

[image]

I don't know if I'm clear?

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var y = window.height;
var items = $('items selector');


items.each(function(i){
   var that = $(this);
   var height = that.height();
   var coord = that.offset();
   var itemBottom = coord.top+height;
   if(y < itemBottom){
      that.hide();
   }
});
```

That should work I guess, I havent;t test it though but if you have a clue you'll be able to make it work if you don't let me know.
Also if you need explanation on what code does I'll explain it, either.
It wpuld be better if you fix it with css or double think your layout approach.

Comment: I try something... The last element is blinking but not hided correctly and I don't know why. Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MJ9VC/ Can someone take a look? For testing, resize the browser, make it smaller (height) you'll see the last element blinking (hiding/showing). Thanks.

Comment: Well it would be better if you use the css:visibility property. The bug comes from that the dispaly:none; element doesn't have height and also position so one way is to detect their position at start and only hide them dynamically. So far we were doing both dynamically! Or the css:visibility property as I started here it is:  http://jsfiddle.net/MJ9VC/22/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to don't show the extra items, you can find your height of your page with `$(window).hight()` then plus your other objects and decrease from this. if your items which are in side bar has class, you can calculate your finally count of them from these height, and hide the extra items.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the $(window).height)() and height of one item say

Say window's height is wH and item's height is iH, then do

var n = Math.floor(wH/iH).

n is the no of items you can fit without any cut.